# Is my proof for this completion of a ring not being flat correct?

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra, proof-verification

I wanted to show that for $A = K[X_i, i \in \mathbb{N}]/(X_iX_j)_{i,j \in \mathbb{N}}$ the completion $A[T] \rightarrow A[|T|]$ is not flat.

However, my proof seems a bit simple/ direct to me, so I'm a little worried that I made a stupid flaw.

Consider the inclusion of the principal ideal $(X_0) \rightarrow A$.

Then after tensoring with $A[|T|]$ over $A$, it is $X_0T \neq 0 \in (X_0) \otimes A[|T|]$, but in $A[|T|]$: $X_0T= X_0(T+ \sum_{i \geq 2} X_iT^i) = X_0T(1+ \sum_{i \geq 2} X_i T^{i-1})$.

The right factor is a unit, hence $X_0T=0$ or $\sum_{i \geq 2} X_i T^{i-1} = 0$. In a similar manner I can show $\sum_{i \geq 3} X_i T^{i-1} =0$ and deduce that $X_iT=0$ for all $i$.

Aside from a correction/pointing out the mistake in my proof, I'd be very happy to see more examples of non-flat completion.

Comment: If $a=au$, $u$ unit, then $a=0$ or $u=1$???

Comment: Ok, take $a=2$, $u=3$ in $Z/4Z$ for an easy counter example. Any idea how to tackle the problem then?

Comment: It was an old homework from an Algebra lecture I attended. As stated I'm also interested in other examples (with proof), as it's more important for me to "have an example" than to "have the particular example written above". (It's also quite critical for me that the ideal we complete on is principal.)

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Do you have a reference for the statement that $A[|X|]$ flat $\Leftrightarrow A$ coherent?

Comment: I've found a reference now! Thank you again, but still I am interested in more explicite examples with explicite proofs (as in your answer), if anyone knows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although I don't have an elementary argument for your particular case, let me say that any ring which is not coherent is good (see [here](https://mathoverflow.net/a/147295)), and it's easy to check that your ring isn't coherent.

Other example: $A=K[Y,X_0,\dots,X_n,\dots]/(YX_0, X_0-YX_1,\dots,X_n-YX_{n+1},\dots)$. Note that $y-T$ is a non-zero divisor in $A[T]$ and $(y-T)\sum_{i\ge 0} x_iT^i=0$ in $A[[T]]$.

Comment: Another example: Bourbaki, *Commutative Algebra*, Chapter 3, Section 3, Exercise 14b).